# internal error while starting android studio

Tags: java, android, java-7

I am trying to start android studio. I have already installed `jdk7` in my computer but when i start android studio, it shows below error message:

> Internal error. Please report to
>   https://code.google.com/p/android/issues
>
> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Argument for @NotNull parameter 'name' of
>   com/android/tools/idea/welcome/Platform. must not be null
>       at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:178)
>       at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1$1$1.run(MainImpl.java:52)
>       at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:312)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:745)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:715)
>       at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:362)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91) Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument for @NotNull
>   parameter 'name' of com/android/tools/idea/welcome/Platform.
>   must not be null
>       at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.Platform.(Platform.java)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.Platform.getLatestPlatform(Platform.java:72)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.Platform.createSubtree(Platform.java:89)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.InstallComponentsPath.createComponentTree(InstallComponentsPath.java:81)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.InstallComponentsPath.init(InstallComponentsPath.java:215)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.DynamicWizardPath.attachToWizard(DynamicWizardPath.java:97)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.DynamicWizard.addPath(DynamicWizard.java:233)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.FirstRunWizard.init(FirstRunWizard.java:75)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.FirstRunWizardHost.setupWizard(FirstRunWizardHost.java:100)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.FirstRunWizardHost.getWelcomePanel(FirstRunWizardHost.java:92)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.welcomeScreen.WelcomeFrame.(WelcomeFrame.java:68)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.welcomeScreen.WelcomeFrame.showNow(WelcomeFrame.java:173)
>       at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication$IdeStarter.main(IdeaApplication.java:302)
>       at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:172)

Answer (score 4):

### Try this:

1. Open the folder `bin` under the directory where you installed your Android Studio.
2. Find the file `idea.properties` and open it with Notepad++ / UltraEdit / other plain text editing software.
3. Add `disable.android.first.run=true` as the final line and save the file.
4. Restart Android Studio.

Comment: how to fix this in macbook ??